# Eclipse content assist causes "Next Editor" with multiple editor windows

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete, content-assist

When I "tear off" (detach) multiple editor windows in Eclipse, content assist (autocompletion) causes a "Next Editor" transition.  I'm using the Java editor.

I've looked through all of the relevant Preferences and Key Bindings, but I haven't found anything which affects this behavior.

Eclipse version info:

Version: Luna Service Release 1a (4.4.1)
Build id: 20150109-0600

My environment is not heavily customized, so I'm surprised to not see others running into this.

Gary

Answer (score 0):

From your description i assume the problem is that once you trigger content assist in a detached editor, the next detached editor will get the focus.

You may have done so already, but check the key bindings at *Preferences > General > Keys*. Search for "Next Editor" and then for "Content Assist" and see whether the two commands share the same key binding as Content Assist. If they do, change the key binding of one of them.

Comment: Hi Johannes -- thanks for responding.  Yes, I have checked this, but not quite in the manner you suggest.  "Next Editor" is not bound to anything.  "Content Assist" is bound to "^space", the default I think.  Tried even unbinding "Content Assist", no help.  I'm using the vim emulator "vrapper".  I have a feeling that might be related or even causing the problem.